# Referencing properties of Observable class in Android Data Binding layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

What is the type of the `Observable` class property which getter is annotated as `@Bindable` in the Android Data Binding framework?

For example, let the `Observable` class be defined as follows:

```
class Localization() : BaseObservable() {

    var translation: (key: String) -> String by Delegates.observable(defaultTranslation) { _, _, _ ->
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.translation)
    }
        @Bindable get
}
```

The layout XML will be then something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="translation"
            type="WHAT IS THE TYPE OF TRANSLATION?" />

    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{translation.invoke(stringKey)}" />

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

The question is, what to put in the `type` attribute of `variable` "translation".

I've tried:

```
type="kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1&lt;String, String&gt;"
```

It compiles, but the `TextView` is not updated when translation property changes.

I can achieve the desired behavior by introducing `localization` variable in the layout XML and then calling `localization.translation.invoke()` in the binding expression. I am just not comfortable with this and want to know if I can reference `translation` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Localization` extends `BaseObservable` while `Function1` is not observable at all. So using the `Localization` gives you an interface for observing the changes to the properties.

If you bind the `translation`, it's a simple field that gets set. If you want to update it, you'd have to call `setTranslation()` again.

Comment: Thanks. Your first sentence allowed me to re-read and re-think how Android Data Binding deals with `Observable` objects. I was missing an important piece in understanding the framework. And regarding my question, no, it is not possible. One should always provide an `Observable` for things to work. Or, to wrap the `translation` into `ObservableField<>`, but this will be stupid, cause `traslation` is already the property of `Observable` and Data Binding can deal with the changes itself, if the getter is properly annotated.